# Audio duration returns nan in AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, swift, wav, avqueueplayer

When I try to play a `.wav` file from server using AVQueuePlayer it returns duration as `nan`.

I used this code to get the duration

```
audioPlayer.currentItem?.duration.seconds 
audioPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration.seconds
```

And I am sure that `.wav` file I am using is not corrupted since its being used by android app and they are able to get the duration.

Below code that I used works perfectly for `.mp3`. but not for `.wav`

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            audioAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: url)

            if let audioAsset = audioAsset {

                let keys = ["playable"]

                   audioAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {

                    let playableStatus = audioAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: keys[0], error: nil)
                    switch playableStatus {

                    case .unknown,  .loading,  .failed,  .cancelled:
                        return

                    case .loaded:

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(asset: audioAsset)
                            self.audioPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
                            self.audioPlayer.play()

                            })
                        }
                        break
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried with `audioAsset.duration` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that too...! Same 'nan'